# Best way to send html form to an email address within Django project?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, forms

I see contact forms on almost all websites and they make it look easy. Reading on how to do it seems complex, especially since most of the solutions are using php and a server. I don't really know php and I already have four languages in my project and it just gets overwhelming. I want something simple; fill out the details, send to an email, and done.

Fill out name: John Doe
Fill out dob: 6/11/2018
[Submit] (send to example@example.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic overview of how that could be accomplished.

Use a form with the details:

```
from django import forms
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = ...
    birht_date = ...
```

Use this form in a view, maybe using [`FormView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

class ContactView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # here you send the email
        send_email(
            sub='New contact: {}'.format(form.cleaned_data['name']),
            msg='This new contact was born  {}'.format(form.cleaned_data['birth_date']),
            from=settings.SERVER_EMAIL,
            to='example@example.com')

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Maybe this puts you an the right track to solve your situation.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this solution out.